# merge branch. - How to ignore certain files while merging?

Tags: git

I have a project, it is deployed on heroku. Now I need to deploy the same project, but with some changes (particularly settings ActionMailer, which are in two different directories).

As a result my second project is a development copy, on which the customer will test the changes. After approval, the changes will be applied on the production server.

I wanted to create two branches, add an exception for certain files and work with it.
please tell me how to do this.

Comment: I'm not sure I got your question correctly, but as for what I can understand from the title, I would
1) commit the non-exceptional files
2) stash the uncommitted changes (exceptional files)
3) merge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to have different configuration settings on different machines.

Here's what I usually do for configuration files:

- Assume I want to configure my application with a file called `config.json`
- Add `config.json` to my `.gitignore`, so it will not be included in the repository
- Create a configuration file template, e.g. `config.json.template` with good defaults
- Add instructions in `README.md` or some other appropriate place that `config.json.template` must be copied to `config.json` and modified appropriately
- Guard my code so that if `config.json` is missing somebody logical is notified when the application starts
- Commit my modified `.gitignore`, my modified documentation, and my new `config.json.template` sample file

When you deploy to a new server, simply copy your template and modify. The `.gitignore` will prevent changes to the config file from being committed, so you should probably be sure to include it as part of your regular backup.

Configuration is data, just like the contents of your database. It should be kept separate from application code.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that, as doing so would completely wreck the concept of completing a merge. Git needs to know/track what commits it has merged into a branch, and "partially" doing that would obviously wreck its ability to know what it has already done.

I would recommend creating a branch and cherry picking the commits which contain the changes you want your client to see while ignoring the rest. Ideally you've made good, logical and contained commits, so this plan of action should work for you.

Comment: What do you think about .gitattributes for some files/dirs with flag "merge=ours"?